# How to read div class contents values using Jsoup in this case

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to use data scrap on a website and trying to read these div below div  data using Jsoup

Comment: you managed to delete your question almost completely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
Elements tickerEl = doc.select(".tickerdata").first();
String valStr = tickerEl.ownText();
Elements spanUpEls = tickerEl.select("span.up");
if (!spanUpEls.isEmpty()){

  String upAbs = spanUpEls.get(0).text();
  String upRel = spanUpEls.get(1).text();
  valStr += " , " + upAbs + " UP";
}
Elements spanDownEls = tickerEl.select("span.down");
if (!spanDownEls.isEmpty()){

  String downAbs = spanDownEls.get(0).text();
  String downRel = spanDownEls.get(1).text();
  valStr += " , " + downAbs + " DOWN";
}
System.out.println(valStr);
```

**EDIT**

I corrected the selector for the tickerdata div. The problem was that we were selecting for a tag named tickerdata (selector `tickerdata`), instead of an element with class tickerdata (selector `.tickerdata` note the dot).

I would advise you to read about [JSoup CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

Comment: Thanks but i am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at this line  String valStr = tickerEl.ownText();

Comment: Please see the Edited part in my question where i had pasted my whole code with what i tried .